# printersetupdialog starting printer

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I'm making an application in Embarcadero Delphi XE2.

I'm using a PrinterSetupDialog to select a printer name into TEdit like:

```
if PrinterSetupDialog1.Execute() then begin

txtPrinterName.Text := Printer.Printers[Printer.PrinterIndex];
ConfigINI.modified := true;

end;
```

The problem I have is that this PrinterSetupDialog when executed, always selects the same printer at start. I can switch to another ok and the TEdit gets filled ok.

---

What I want to do is:

Before executing the PrinterSetupdialog

have it set dialog's selected printer to the one in the TEdit for example:

```
PrinterSetupDialog.PrinterSelectedAtExecute := txtPrinterName.Text;
```

Help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set the initial selected printer of the printer setup dialog using the [`Printer`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Printers.Printer) function.

```
uses
  Printers;
 ...
 ...
 begin
   Printer.PrinterIndex:=Printer.Printers.IndexOf(txtPrinterName.Text);
   PrinterSetupDialog1.Execute;
 end;
```